# Formula for alternating sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, functions

I am looking for a general formula for alternating sequences.
I know that the formula $f(x)=(-1)^x$ gives the sequence $1,-1,1,-1,...$ but I want more a general formula; for example the function $f(a,b,x)$ which returns the series $a,b,a,b,a,b,...$ as $x$ increases.

So for example the function $f(3,5,x)$ returns the series $3,5,3,5,3,5,...$
What would such a function $f(a,b,x)$ be?

Comment: You seem to be using "function" in the colloquial sense of a formula. Hirshy's answer uses "function" in the technical mathematical sense of a relation.

Comment: $\tfrac12((a+b)-(-1)^n(a-b))$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\frac{a+b}{2}+(-1)^{n-1}\cdot\frac{a-b}{2}\ \ (n=1,2,\cdots)$$
represents $a,b,a,b,\cdots$.

Answer (score 3):

$f(a,b,x)=\tfrac12((a+b)-\cos(\pi x)(a-b))$

Answer (score 0):

How about: $$f(n)=\begin{cases} 3 & n\equiv 1\mod 2 \\ 5 & n\equiv 0 \mod 2\end{cases}$$

This gives $f(n)=3$ for every odd $n$ and $f(n)=5$ for every even $n$.

**Edit** As pointed out in the comments: $$f(a,b,n)=\begin{cases} a & n\equiv 1 \mod 2 \\ b & n\equiv 0 \mod 2\end{cases}\quad (n=1,2,\dots)$$ will work for arbitrary $a,b\in\mathbb R$. This can be easily generalised to sequences with more than two different numbers: $$f(a,b,c,n)=\begin{cases} a & n\equiv 1 \mod 3 \\ b & n\equiv 2 \mod 3 \\ c & n\equiv 0 \mod 3\end{cases}$$ for a sequence with three different numbers and finally $$f(a_1,a_2,\dots, a_n,n)=\begin{cases} a_1 & n\equiv 1 \mod n \\ \vdots \\ a_n & n\equiv 0 \mod n\end{cases}$$ for $n$ different numbers.

Comment: They mean for 3 and 5 to be arguments to the function, such that $f(1,2,x) = 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2$ and $f(9,11,x) = 9, 11, 9, 11, 9, 11$.

Comment: @Axoren one can easily write this as $$f(3,5,n)=\begin{cases} 3 & n\equiv 1\mod 2 \\ 5 & n\equiv 0 \mod 2\end{cases}$$ if the numbers $3$ and $5$ should be included as arguments.

Comment: Do you mean the following?

$$f(a,b,n)=\begin{cases} a & n\equiv 1\mod 2 \\ b & n\equiv 0 \mod 2\end{cases}$$

Edit: Just saw your edit, that's what you meant.

Comment: *dang* I just realised what you meant; I was to focused on the sequence given by Hector, that I didn't think this all the way through.

Comment: @Axoren thank you for pointing that out, I edited my answer for a more useful/correct function.